# Should I use enums or arrays for a dynamic data source?

Tags: ios, array, enum

I've inherited an iOS project that uses [NS_Enum](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) to store the number of rows and sections in a [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html) At the moment, the UITableView is static; no rows are being added to it. However, that is what I need to change...I need to be able to dynamically add and delete additional rows.

However, I'm don't yet understand how to dynamically add additional elements to my enums that store the number of rows of my table-view.

This is probably due to not yet *fully* understanding when and when not to use enums. When is it appropriate to use an enum vs. an array? In terms of creating a dynamic data source, an array seems more appropriate to use then an enum, but I want to make sure I understand exactly why that is. Thank you!

Comment: Enums are static, defined at compile time. I am not familiar with ios development myself but I imagine there would be some type of model that backs that view. Have you looked into that view class and how to make it display records?